# Row count and similar in Esqueleto

Tags: haskell, esqueleto

Ok, I'll be more concrete

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Database.Persist.TH
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Esqueleto
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Topic
   title String
|]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  runSqlite "test.sqlite" $ do
       runMigration migrateAll
       [Value c1] <- select $
                     from $ \t ->
                     do
                           return countRows
       liftIO $ putStrLn $ show (c1 :: Int)
```

This code causes an error

```
est2.hs:26:22: error:
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘from’
  prevents the constraint ‘(From
                              SqlQuery SqlExpr SqlBackend a0)’ from being solved.
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

That is because the compiler does not know, which table it must use to calculate the count of rows. This thing may be done with a workaround like

```
   [Value c1] <- select $
                 from $ \t ->
                     do
                       orderBy [asc (t ^. TopicTitle)]
                       return countRows
   liftIO $ putStrLn $ show (c1 :: Int)
```

However, this is awkful, dull and artifical. Is there another, simplier way to fix this code?

The *answer* is:

We ought to state the table, in which the rows will be counted. The easiest way for this is to use ScopedTypeVariables language extension, and describe locally the types of arguments:

`[Value c2] <- select $
                     from $ \(_ :: SqlExpr (Entity Topic)) ->
                         do
                           return countRows`

Comment: Please include an esqueleto schema to run these queries against.

Comment: Ok, I've found the answer here: https://github.com/bitemyapp/esqueleto/issues/103

Comment: Would you condense that discussion into an answer for this site?

Comment: We ought to state the table, in which the rows will be counted. The easiest way for this is to use ScopedTypeVariables language extension, and describe locally the types of arguments:

```
[Value c2] <- select $
                     from $ \(_ :: SqlExpr (Entity Topic)) ->
                         do
                           return countRows
```